# Multiple push notification service in swift apple

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My app using FCM and pushy to deliver notif at the same time, the situation that is happening now is that I am getting two similar notification banners. How do I delete/cancel one of the notification banners when one of them has appeared.

I can handle it when the application is open/foreground, how do I handle it when the application is in background mode and the device gets a remote push notification

```
//notifications while app is in the foreground
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    
    let userInfo  = notification.request.content.userInfo
    let notifID   = (userInfo["notification_id"] as? String) ?? 
    
  
    if arrayOfNotifId.contains(notifID){
        arrayOfNotifId.append(notifID)
    }else{
        arrayOfNotifId.append(notifID)
        completionHandler([[.banner, .badge, .sound]])
    }
}




 //handle notification when app is in bkacground
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        Pushy.shared?.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo, fetchCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
        
         let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.getDeliveredNotifications { id in
            
            
                var count = 1
                for iden in id {
                    if count > 1 {
                        center.removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [iden.request.identifier])
                    }
                    count += 1
                }
        }
        
//         completionHandler(.newData)
    }
```

How do I handle this on the frontend side? If it is not possible/not recommended, can you please provide documentation from Apple so that it is best to change it on the server side

Comment: You aren't going to get any documentation from apple; it isn't their architecture. It is yours. Apple don't know anything about FCM or Pushy or any other 3rd party;  they just receive notifications to send and send them. It seems like a bad idea on your side to use two different notification services.

Comment: You can use [`apns-collapse-id`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns) to have iOS replace existing notifications with a new one.

Comment: Why have 2 different services send the same notification, that is a waste of resources. I think the issue should be resolved at that level.

Comment: @Paulw11 
Thank you for your help, It's true that it's very strange to use two notification services at once, and I've tried using the HTTP/2 header "apns-collapse-id" This works and combines the notifications into 1 when the iPhone is locked, while the iPhone is open (unlocked) the notification banner still two. and I didn't find any solution for this except sending the exact same notification only 1 time.

Additionally, why use two notification services? is as a backup, if the first one is not received by the user, then the user can receive the second one, and vice versa

Comment: Ok.  It sounds like you are causing yourself a lot of trouble for a situation that is highly unlikely to arise. Both notification services are dependent on Apple's APNS service to deliver the notification.  FCM is highly unlikely to fail.  Pushy is in AWS - Probably also unlikely to fail if they have architected well.  Pick one service and just use that.